# How to search a collection using lambda expression in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8

There is a `Person` class (with three elements: `person_name`, `age`, `sex`). There is a `List` with 100 `Person` objects.

I need to search this list by `person_name` and implement the search function with a lambda expression.

Comment: @Sotiros, excuse me for over use of need... I would appreciate if you can help me with the solution

Comment: I don't know what to help you with, you haven't asked a question.

Comment: I need a search function to search the List of Persons. The search should be made with Lamba expression.

Comment: Read the javadoc of `Stream`.

Comment: I think I have made it clear about my question

Comment: I don't doubt that @user3677652 could have found this out in stream tutorials or in the documentation but it's also a fairly easy question to answer. For further info, start with the tutorial on aggregate operations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
public Optional<Person> findPersonByName(final List<Person> list, final String name) {
    return list.stream().filter(p -> p.getName().equals(name)).findAny();
}
```

It returns an `Optional` so you will need to test it to see if a value is present. Or you can use `orElse(null)` if you prefer to get a null back on a failed search.

Comment: As the commentors on your question noted, this is dealt with pretty well in the Java documentation. I suggest you start with the tutorial on aggregate operations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html.

Comment: excuse me, if the method returns a list, why the signature is Optional<Person> and not Optional<List.... ?

Comment: @jpganz18 The method doesn't return a list. It returns zero or one person objects, depending on whether there is a person of the given name. hence the optional.